# Proof that Fock space is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{H}^{n} := \overbrace{\mathcal{H}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{H}}^{\text{$n$ times}}$. Here, $\mathcal{H}^{0} := \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{H}^{1} := \mathcal{H}$. I know that each $\mathcal{H}^{n}$ is a Hilbert space. We define the Fock space $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$ as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H}) := \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{H}^{n} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{H}^{n}$ is the set of all sequences $\varphi = (\varphi_{0},\varphi_{1},...)$, $\varphi_{n} \in \mathcal{H}^{n}$, such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi_{n}||^{2} < +\infty$. I want to show that $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$ is a Hilbert space when equipped with the inner product:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \varphi, \psi \rangle := \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle \varphi_{n},\psi_{n}\rangle \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}

**My proof:** Let $\{\varphi^{(n)}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$. Here, each $\varphi^{(n)}$ is again a sequence $\{\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\in \mathcal{H}^{k}$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for all $n,m > n_{0}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
||\varphi^{(n)}-\varphi^{(m)}||^{2} = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi^{(m)}_{k}||^{2} < \epsilon^{2} \Rightarrow ||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi^{(m)}_{k}||^{2}<\epsilon^{2} \quad (\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, for each fixed $k$, the sequence $\{\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{H}^{k}$. Because $\mathcal{H}^{k}$ is Hilbert, there exists, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$, an element $\varphi_{k}\in \mathcal{H}^{k}$ such that $\varphi^{(n)}_{k} \to \varphi_{k}$ when $n\to \infty$. Using (\ref{3}), if $n,m > n_{0}$ and $N\ge 1$, we have:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}||\varphi_{k}^{(n)}-\varphi_{k}^{(m)}||^{2} < \epsilon^{2} $$
and, thus, taking $m\to \infty$ we obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi_{k}||^{2} \le \epsilon. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{eqnarray}
We can now take $N\to \infty$ in (\ref{4}), to obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi||^{2} = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi_{k}||^{2}<\epsilon^{2} \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{eqnarray}
Where $\varphi := \{\varphi_{k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$. Our $\varphi$ is the natural candidate for limit for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\varphi^{(n)}$ but we need to prove that it is an element of $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{H})$. To do it, first note that $\varphi_{k}=\varphi_{k}^{(n)}+(\varphi_{k}-\varphi_{k}^{(n)})$. Therefore:
\begin{eqnarray}
||\varphi_{k}||^{2} = \langle \varphi_{k}^{(n)}+(\varphi_{k}-\varphi_{k}^{(n)}), \varphi_{k}^{(n)}+(\varphi_{k}-\varphi_{k}^{(n)})\rangle = \langle \varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\rangle + \langle \varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\rangle + \langle \varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi_{k}\rangle + \langle \varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\rangle \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus:
\begin{align}
||\varphi_{k}||^{2} &\le ||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}+||\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}+|\langle \varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\rangle | + |\langle \varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k},\varphi^{(n)}_{k}\rangle| \nonumber \\ 
&\le ||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}+||\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}+\overbrace{2||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||||\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||}^{\text{use $2ab \le a^{2}+b^{2}$}}\nonumber \\
&\le 2(||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}+||\varphi_{k}-\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2} ) 
\end{align}
where, in the second inequality, I also used Cauchy-Schwarz. Finally:
$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi_{k}||^{2} \le 2\overbrace{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}||^{2}}^{\text{$<+\infty$}}+2\overbrace{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}||\varphi^{(n)}_{k}-\varphi_{k}||^{2}}^{\text{$<\epsilon^{2}$ by (\ref{5})}} < +\infty$$

Is my proof correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks OK to me, including the critical step (5).  I would suggest proving the same result in the slightly more general case where $H^n$ is an abstract Hilbert space, rather than the tensor product, since this will (1) be more general and (2) avoid tensor products which, after all, play no role in the proof but might pollute the mind of the reader.

Comment: Nice comment! Indeed, what you said is really reasonable. Thanks so much!